# Spring Integration and Spring MVC: @Controller vs inbound-gateway with service-activator

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I want to find the best way to manage an inbound request with **Spring Integration HTTP** and **Spring MVC**.

I have an `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` configured as follows:

```
<!-- CHANNEL -->
<int:channel id="requestChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="outputChannel" />

<!-- INBOUND GATEWAY -->
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="gateway" request-channel="requestChannel"
              path="/service/**" 
              supported-methods="POST"
              reply-channel="outputChannel"
              header-mapper="headerMapper">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<!-- SERVICE ACTIVATOR -->
<int:service-activator id="channelServiceActivator"
    ref="channelService"
    input-channel="requestChannel"
    output-channel="outputChannel"
    method="manage"/>

<bean id="channelService"
    class="test.spring.data.rest.xml.channel.ChannelService"/>
```

With this integration, every HTTP call made on the path URI: `/service/**` is handled in the *"`manage()`"* method of the `ChannelService` class.

This is the `ChannelService` class:

```
public class ChannelService {

    public void manage(Message<?> message){

        // how to get the HttpServletRequest request here ???
    }

}
```

It works: the *"manage()"* method is correctly executed and the message contains the right payload. 
But there is a little issue: **I don't have any reference to the HttpServletRequest received in input in that ServiceChannel**.

If I use a `@Controller` of Spring MVC, I can handle every request with the relative `@RequestMapping`.
If I want to read the payload contained in the request, I have to read it from the inputStream of the HttpServletRequest. Anywhere, I have no chance to get the message passed in the channel:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/service")
public class ServiceController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/**")
    public handle(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{

        // how to get the Message<?> message passed on the channel here ???

    }

}
```

**If I use both** (`@Controller` and `inbound-gateway`), **the @Controller mapping wins over the inbound-gateway**: there is no chance to handle a servlet path URI with an `inbound-gateway` if there is
a `@Controller` that maps the same path URI.

So, I want to understand if there is some way to have a `Message<?> message` in the @Controller, or the HttpServletRequest in the ServiceActivator, or another way to manage this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the `HttpServletRequest`  via `MessageHeaders` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#_uri_template_variables_and_expressions).

The `HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport` has a logic like:

```
evaluationContext.setVariable("requestAttributes", RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes());

MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = this.convertParameterMap(servletRequest.getParameterMap());
evaluationContext.setVariable("requestParams", requestParams);

evaluationContext.setVariable("requestHeaders", new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest).getHeaders());
```

So, you can configure your `<int-http:inbound-gateway>` with sub-elements like:

```
<int-http:header name="requestAttributes" expression="#requestAttributes"/>
<int-http:header name="requestParams" expression="#requestParams"/>
<int-http:header name="requestHeaders" expression="#requestHeaders"/>
<int-http:header name="matrixVariables" expression="#matrixVariables"/>
<int-http:header name="cookies" expression="#cookies"/>
```

The `requestAttributes` is an implementation of `RequestAttributes`. The standard one is `ServletRequestAttributes`, where you can find `getRequest()` method. And yeah, use it in the expression as well:

```
<int-http:header name="request" expression="#requestAttributes.request"/>
```

On the other hand you always can use `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` in your own code, because it is tied with `ThreadLocal`.

The Spring MVC knows nothing about Spring Integration, therefore there is no any `Message` deal with.

Anyway you can go that way too. For this purpose you should introduce `@MessagingGateway` and delegate a logic there from your `@Controller`.

Comment: Thank you very much Artem for your brilliant explanation.